# JSP to insert image into DB, display it to client

Tags: image, postgresql, jsp

I want to insert an image to database and display it in another page. I am using the PostgreSQL database.

My guide suggests that I insert the image with its file path in the database. When displaying, in place of the `src` attrib of `img` tag put the path from database. So can I get any help for this .

Please guide me for this or give me link for similar kind of problem.

(I'm a final year student, and feel that this project requirement is difficult).

Answer (score 1):

Your guide is entirely correct. Part of what you are supposed to be learning is problem solving: how to break a big problem down into many smaller, simpler problems you can solve piece by piece. It sounds like it's hinting at this, but expects you to be able to do that yourself, which is pretty reasonable.

You need to break this down into steps, and do each step in isolation. That's how anything but the most trivial programming task must be done.

(It isn't clear if you want to store the image *data* in the DB, or just a file system path, by the way, so I'm assuming you want to write the file to the local file system and just store the path in the DB).

Anyway, this should be fairly simple JSP. To display:

- One JSP that:

  - Examines the query parameters for the image ID
  - Uses JDBC to fetch the associated path of the image on the file system from the database (a simple `SELECT` using the image ID as a query parameter)
  - Opens the image on the file system as a binary stream; also stats it to get its size
  - Sends appropriate HTTP headers eg `Content-Type: image/jpeg` and `Content-Length: image-length-in-bytes` to the client
  - Copies the raw image data from the image input stream to the output stream that sends to the client
- Another JSP that generates the HTML and has an `<img src="/the/image/jsp?imageid=blah">` link in it.

If you're required to submit just one JSP file, you can combine the two by having the JSP show a HTML page if it doesn't receive any query parameters, and send an image if it does receive an image id as a query parameter.

To insert:

- One JSP that displays a HTML form with a file upload link if it doesn't get called with any HTTP POST data
- If the JSP does get called with HTTP POST data:
  ** Issue a JDBC `INSERT` to create a record for the file in the database, but do not commit
  ** Access and decode the POST data using the methods provided in JSP
  ** Extract the desired file name from the form data and open a binary output stream to a file on the filesystem with that name
  ** Copy the image bytes into that output stream, url-decoding if required (the HTTP POST form handling code in JSP is likely to decode it to a byte stream for you, though)
  ** Flush and close the output stream
  ** Commit the transaction with the JDBC `INSERT`.

You should be able to find numerous examples of both with a quick Google search. If you can't, adapting examples from other programming languages should be easy enough.

For inserting you must think carefully about the error cases. That's a large part of proper programming.

I am intentionally not showing you code examples. You should be able to do this yourself if you're a final year student. You won't know everything you need, but by now you should know *how to find out what you don't know when you need to know it*. Tutorials. Documentation. Google. Writing test programs to figure things out. Method name autocomplete in NetBeans / Eclipse. Adapting sample code. You've got lots of options.

Comment: Thank u . . now I got an idea . .

Comment: When I call request.getParameter("photo") in servlet it only inserting the image name.

Comment: I think you need to go to your tutor or whoever else is responsible for your course and request some one-on-one assistance from them. You're missing some of the fundamental concepts you need to understand for this kind of thing, and if you're in final year, that means you're in trouble and need to get some intensive tutoring right now. Most course staff are very happy to help students who're finding something difficult, and can talk you through any issues in more detail than I can here. (For one thing, I can't see your code).

Comment: You also need to start figuring things out piece by piece. So, you've sent what's pesumably an `<input type="file" name="photo"/>` in a HTTP POST form submission to your JSP. It isn't giving you the result you expected, just the file name. Well, did you [search for how to access the data from a HTML form file upload in JSP](http://google.com/search?q=how+to+access+the+data+from+a+HTML+form+file+upload+in+JSP)? If you're stuck, research the problem. Break it down into smaller pieces. Seriously [focus on your problem solving skills](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/35594)